# How to upload an image with other data in NestJS?

Tags: html, angular, post, file-upload, nestjs

I want to add a product to database from the client side. I use Angular and NestJS.

Those are the fields I need to provide:

```js
export interface Product {
    id?: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    sale: boolean;
    image: string;
    genre: string;
    saleval?: number;
}
```

I used a bootstrap modal to contain the form:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row g-2">
    <div class="form-floating col-auto">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="name" required>
      <label class="ms-1" for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating col-auto">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" id="price" [(ngModel)]="price" step="0.01" required>
      <label class="ms-1" for="price">Price</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row g-2 mt-3">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="category" value="Food" placeholder="Food" disabled readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="genre" value="fruits" placeholder="Fruits" disabled readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg" value="" [(ngModel)]="image" name="file" class="form-control mt-3">
  <textarea class="form-control mt-2" cols="30" [(ngModel)]="description" placeholder="Description (max.100 char)" maxlength="100"></textarea>
  <div class="mt-2">
    <label class="me-2" for="sale">On Sale</label>
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="isSale()">
  </div>
  <div class="" [ngClass]="sale ? 'not-hidden' : 'visually-hidden'">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Enter the discount percentage!" min="0" max="100" step="0.01">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="postFood()">Add</button>
</div>
```

I tried doing a regular Post call from the server

food.component.ts

```js
name: string;
price: number;
category: string;
genre: string;
image: string;
description: string;
sale: boolean = false;
saleVal: number;

postFood() {
    if (this.sale == false) {
      this.saleVal = 0
    }
    if (this.saleVal == 0) {
      this.sale = false
    }
    const product: Product = {
      name: this.name,
      price: this.price,
      description: this.description,
      category: this.category,
      sale: this.sale,
      image: this.image,
      genre: this.genre,
      saleval: this.saleVal
    }
    this.productsService.postFood(product)
  }
```

products.service.

```js
postFood(product: Product) {
    console.log('Food is added successfully to database!')
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/food', product)
}
```

food.controller.ts

```js
 @Post()
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
async create(
    @Body() product: Product,
    @UploadedFile() image: Express.Multer.File,
) {
    product.image = image.buffer.toString()
    console.log(product)
    return this.productsService.create(product);
  }
}
```

products.service.ts(Back-end):

```js
 async create(product: Product): Promise<any> {
    return await this.productsRepository.save(product);
}
```

..But it didn't work. I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6AR7.png)

I thought of putting the image uploading part in a seperate path and putting it in another Post call for example `@Post(':id/upload')`, but I dont know how I can get the ID of the product to update it.

Answer (score 0):

you should be the same fieldName in @UseInterceptors and @UploadedFile() below.

```
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
async create(
    @Body() product: Product,
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
) {
    product.file= file.buffer.toString()
    console.log(product)
    return this.productsService.create(product);
  }
}
```